# Python XML attribute returns 'None'

Tags: python, python-2.7, xml-parsing

I am trying to print two different attributes out of a specific XML with Python. My XML file and the Python script I am trying to create are below. I get the first print correctly but not the second one.

**XML:**

```
<PreExecuteXml>
    <xmlElement>
        <action actionType="PlayGame" ugiToken="18638826-ecad-4e1a-a005-2306d3e68c99" uToken="2f53297e-5b88-55d7-b1dd-22fb9278ab29" msgId="jf5o4rtj447">
            <messages>
                <message type="Main">
                    <slotGame gsid="5752276184208378" mode="Fun" gi="52">
                        <request lin="10" linBet="1" denom="0.01" action="SPIN" bonLevel="" />
                    </slotGame>
                </message>
            </messages>
            <error HasError="false" />
            <creditBalance>0</creditBalance>
        </action>
    </xmlElement>
</PreExecuteXml>
```

**Python Script:**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree

xmlReq = xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring(str(open("xml.txt", "rb").read()))
element = xmlReq.find("xmlElement/action")
action = element.attrib.get("actionType")

spinElement = xmlReq.find("xmlElement/action/messages/message/slotGame/request")
actionz = element.attrib.get("action")

print action #Prints -> "PlayGame" (correct)
print actionz #Prints -> None (Should print "SPIN")
```

**Result:**

```
C:\tests>python xmlz.py
PlayGame
None
```

Comment: You're calling `attrib.get('action')` on `element` instead of on `spinElement`, so there is no such attribute. I'm guessing this is a simple typo (it's always hard to spot these in your own code you've been staring at…).

Comment: @abarnert typo confirmed. Thank you!